# Shuffle items in block on Google form with Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I m creating a quiz. I have the pattern like

Item 1 ,an image of Q1

Item 2 , multiple choice options abcd for Q1

Item 3 ,an image of Q2

Item 4 , multiple choice options abcd for Q2

...

I would like to shuffle the questions.

The default shuffle function provide by Google form doesn't work for me

It may give me something like

Item 1 ,an image of Q1

Item 2 ,an image of Q2

Item 3 , multiple choice options abcd for Q1

Item 4 , multiple choice options abcd for Q2

anyway to do my kind of shuffle with script?

So that every response see the question in different order?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: What have you learned so far in your research of this question?